# Perhaps we need a [windows-forms] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I don't like tag pollution, and [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) is a perfectly good tag.

But I keep seeing [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms) questions tagged [windows-forms-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-designer).  I'm assuming that this is because newbies start typing in the Tags textbox and get as far as [windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms) and think "well, I am using the designer, so... good enough"

A [windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms) tag would simply be synonym of [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms), but be there for folks who don't know the usual abbreviation.

What do you folks think?

Comment: Huh? Isn't [windows-forms] already a synonym of [winforms]?

Comment: @41686d6564 it is https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winforms/synonyms so ... [status-completed] ...

Comment: And a whole bunch of permutations as well based on a (giant?) **S**

Comment: To make things even more interesting and abiguous, windows have always been called "forms" in Delphi and C++ Builder, which pre-dates .NET quite a bit. And iirc old pre-.NET VB also called them forms (and VBA too?). Looking at for example posts tagged `[winforms] [delphi]` then there's some 20-30 or so questions using the winforms tag incorrectly, actually referring to the Delphi GUI lib called VCL.

Comment: @Lundin, should it be [tag:forms]+[tag:delphi] or what are correct tags (delphi is not mentioned in the [forms tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/forms/info))?

Comment: @Sinatr That is probably more correct yeah.

Comment: If I go to ask a question and I type `windows-for` into the Tags box, I do see `winforms` as a suggestion (along with `windows-forms-designer` and a few others), but not `windows-forms`.  Yeah, the notes for `winforms` talk about "Windows Forms", but Newbies are newbies.  Perhaps we should make `windows-forms` the tag and make `winforms` the synonym

Comment: Do we really need a [tag:windows-forms-designer] tag? Why can't it just be synonymized to [tag:winforms]?

Answer (score 10):

> Perhaps we need a [windows-forms] tag?

We already have said tag. Probably the solution you are actually looking for is to remove [windows-forms-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-forms-designer) instead, since questions about it, should use [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) (if they are actually about that functionality of VS).

So, lets turn the request around. Since windows-forms-designer is being misused and confused with the winforms tag, lets remove it and you won't observe the issue you bring: winforms questions tagged windows-forms-designer.

Comment: I'm still wondering if it wouldn't make sense to make `windows-forms` (the formal name for the feature) be the main tag and `winforms` (a well known alias for _Windows Forms__ be the synonym

Comment: @Flydog57 because that has nothing to do with the issue you are complaining about. Focus on that. Your other "solution" would not make a significant difference.

Comment: It is the "new" .NET Core Windows Forms and the new Designer in Visual Studio and the new Core based assemblies specific to this new stack that is different from the classic Framework forms that I would want to see a tag for.  I have encountered many specific details related only to the new core forms that I have wanted to post a solution and warning on stackoverflow about - but there was no specific tag to use so I did not post my discovery.   I would welcome a tag that encompasses the IDE the runtime and compile time.

Comment: @SqlSurfer it doesn't really matter. Since the designer is a feature of visual studio, using the VS tag should be enough.

Comment: Visual Studio has multiple designers -- Windows Forms, WPF, Xamarin, etc.

Comment: @Slapout exactly, they are features of the IDE. If you didn't use Visual Studio, you would not use those designers, but either copying them from SO or using something else :D

Comment: But people could have questions related to a specific designer.

Comment: @Slapout for that there's the title and body of the question ;). Would you believe that someone that doesn't know anything about visual studio would be able to answer questions about just the designer? That's what tags say: this topic is not contained in any other topic.

Comment: @SqlSurfer Please don't let the lack of a tag prevent you from asking. If you want to ask a question about Windows Forms in .NET Core, use [winforms] [.net-core]; that should be sufficient to clue people in on what you're asking about (that and, you know, the text of your question) :).

Comment: There's also a `windows-forms-core` tag.

Comment: _"for that there's the title and body of the question"_ -- well, no. The search function on Stack Overflow is notoriously poor, and tags are one of the only things that helps it focus search results in a useful way. If one is looking specifically for Q&A about the Winforms Designer, having to wade through _every_ Visual Studio-related question (especially given how often _that_ tag is misused for any random .NET-language question) is not nearly as useful as having a Designer-specific tag. Heck, even having a `[designer]` tag not specific to a particular API is useful in that respect.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Use Google. No one should use the SE search if they are looking for solutions to problems. If you are looking for questions of Visual Studio to answer, visual-studio is the tag you are looking for. 99.999999999% of users use Google for something. The tag being there or not wouldn't affect them.

Comment: Right. So we should just remove the Stack Overflow search feature altogether. That makes _perfect_ sense.

Comment: @PeterDuniho honestly, I don't see why not. It's subpar compared to the alternative for all use cases. SEDE and Google are just that good.

Comment: You're certainly welcome to your opinion, but until Stack Overflow policy is in fact that no one should use the search feature and they remove it, other site features cannot ignore their impact on the in-site search.

Comment: @PeterDuniho well, SE has pretty crappy policies as of late. So, having a in-site search is probably just one of the older ones.

Comment: @PeterDuniho btw, of all hits per day only 0.19% are /search according to [this blog post.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/) So, those are rare.

Comment: _"those are rare"_ -- I wouldn't say so. You're misinterpreting the data on that page. Even ignoring the fact that you're looking at the graph that includes automated traffic, by the standard you've applied, Stack Overflow could get rid of everything except the actual questions, deleting all other site features. Are you really suggesting that's what SO policy should be? Measured a more informative way, the search accounts for somewhere between 10-15% of traffic other than viewing the pages themselves. I wouldn't call that "rare".

Comment: And you're also ignoring that the ListByTag is also a significant source of traffic, at an even higher rate that the Search category. Fact is, tags are clearly of significant use on the site, potentially used in as much as a third or more of the traffic not involved in actually _looking_ at a page. That's far from "rare".

Comment: @PeterDuniho well, I'm just spitballing ideas since you seem to have a problem and I want to solve it. I don't know what you think I'm doing. I'm just saying that maybe the thing you think is not generally applicable. So is the problem that you identify. For me, there's no problem with not keeping these tags since "the problem" is better solved elsewhere.